# How to render gease pencil in cycles in blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, grease-pencil, bevel

How can I render grease pencil lines in cycles? Other stack exchange questions explain that you need to bevel the lines, but that option seems to have disappeared. I have markings on some objects that I made with the grease pencil, and they don't show up in the final render, though they do show up in the preview render (when you press z, and select uv, rendered, lookdev, solid). Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. After the render finishes, the lines are added, so you have to wait throught the whole render.